# Present perfect or past perfect in “The critique, provided to me this weekend by a prominent diplomat who has lived in Washington a long time”

Tags: tenses, present-tense, perfect-aspect

Is the usage of the Present Perfect Tense, "has lived", correct in the sentence below? Should it be the Past Perfect tense instead?

> “The critique, provided to me this weekend by a prominent diplomat who has lived in Washington a long time”.

Comment: Yes, it is correct if the diplomat still lives in Washington.

Answer (score 0):

This is valid and natural English from a U.K. perspective. It’s ambiguous as to whether they still live there, but it’s likely to be taken that they do.